# SQL Server error simplify code due to multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need an alternative way to simplify this code.

This code computes the age of the balances of the client depending on the repayment schedule of loan. The filters are 1-7 days, 8-30, 31-60 .... and so on until it reach 181 and above

```
with membersWithLoans as -- gets members with loan
(
    select 
        a.memberid, a.loanid, a.loanamt, a.intamt
    from 
        loanmst a
    where 
        loandt <= '12/19/2016'
        and status = 'O'
)
,selectPaymentToDate as -- gets payments of the members to date
(
    select 
        b.loanid, sum(a.princollamt) as princollamt1, 
        sum(a.intcollamt) as intcollamt1
    from 
        collectiondtl a
    inner join 
        membersWithLoans b on a.loanid = b.loanid
    where 
        a.accdate <= '12/19/2016'
    group by 
        b.loanid)
,selectBalanceToDate as -- gets the balance of member to date
(
    select 
        b.loanid, 
        sum(a.princeamt) as prinBalanceToDate, 
        sum(a.instamt) as intBalanceToDate,
        sum(a.insamt) as insuBalanceToDate
    from 
        loandtl a
    inner join 
        membersWithLoans b on a.loanid = b.loanid
    where 
        a.duedt <= '12/19/2016'
    group by 
        b.loanid)
, combineBalanceWithpayment as -- combine payment and balance
(
    select a.loanid,a.loanamt, a.intamt, 
(case
when b.prinBalanceToDate is null then 0
else b.prinBalanceToDate end) as prinBalanceToDate2,
(case
when b.intBalanceToDate is null then 0
else b.intBalanceToDate end) as intBalanceToDate2,
(case
when b.insuBalanceToDate is null then 0
else b.insuBalanceToDate end) as insuBalanceToDate2,
(case
when c.princollamt1 is null then 0
else c.princollamt1 end) as PrincipalCollectiontoDate,
(case
when c.intcollamt1 is null then 0
else c.intcollamt1 end) as IntCollectiontoDate,

cast(((case
when b.prinBalanceToDate is null then 0
else b.prinBalanceToDate 
end)
-
(case
when c.princollamt1 is null then 0
else c.princollamt1 end))as decimal(10,2)) as Arrears
from
membersWithLoans a
left join selectBalanceToDate b
on a.loanid=b.loanid
left join selectPaymentToDate c
on a.loanid=c.loanid
)

,filterNegativeArrears as
(
select * 
from
combineBalanceWithpayment
where Arrears > 0
)
```

the code above gets the member information

```
,select1To7days as -- this code gets amount to be paid in a specific schedule
(
select b.loanid,
    sum((case
    when a.princeamt is null then 0
    else a.princeamt end))as prin7Daysbalance

from loandtl a
inner join membersWithLoans b
on a.loanid=b.loanid
where 
    a.duedt > DATEADD(day,-7,'12/19/2016')
        and 
    a.duedt<='12/19/2016'
group by b.loanid
)

,select8to30days as -- this code gets amount to be paid in a specific schedule
(
select b.loanid,
    sum((case
    when a.princeamt is null then 0
    else a.princeamt end))as prin8To30Daysbalance
from loandtl a
inner join membersWithLoans b
on a.loanid=b.loanid
where 
    a.duedt<=DATEADD(day,-7,'12/19/2016')
    and a.duedt > DATEADD(day,-30,'12/19/2016')
group by b.loanid
)

-- and so on ..... the filters for schedule is compose of 31 to 60days, 61 to 90 days,
--121 to 180 days, 181  and above. there is no pattern since it the requirement on days may change


, computePar1To7days as -- computes the 1 to 7 days
(
select a.loanid, cast((a.arrears - a.Par1To7days) as decimal(10,2)) as deductedArrears,  a.Par1To7days
from
(
    select a.loanid,a.arrears,
    cast((case
    when a.arrears >=  b.prin7Daysbalance then b.prin7Daysbalance -- if the arrears is greater than the 7days balance to be collected then it will be show 
    else a.arrears end)as decimal(10,2))as Par1To7days -- else the remaining is the arrears
    from 
    filterNegativeArrears a
    left join select1To7days b
    on a.loanid=b.loanid
) a
where cast((a.arrears - a.Par1To7days) as decimal(10,2)) > 0
)

,computePar8To30days as -- computes the 8 to 30 days
(
select a.loanid, cast((a.arrears - a.Par8To30days)as decimal(10,2)) as deductedArrears,  a.Par8To30days
from
(
    select a.loanid, a.deductedArrears as arrears,
    cast((case
    when (a.deductedArrears) > 0
        then 
            (case
                when (a.deductedArrears)>= b.prin8To30Daysbalance 
                    then b.prin8To30Daysbalance
                else (a.deductedArrears) 
            end)
    else 0 end)as decimal(10,2))as Par8To30days

    from computePar1To7days a
    left join select8To30days b
    on a.loanid=b.loanid
) a 
where cast((a.arrears - a.Par8To30days) as decimal(10,2)) > 0
)
-- so on until all par is computed. 31 to 60 days, 61 to 90 days,
--121 to 180 days, 181  and above. there is no pattern since it the requirement on days may change
```

the code above gets the sum of data from specific schedules like
1 to 7 days, 8-30 days, 31 to 60 days, 61 to 90 days, 121 to 180 days, 181  and above

```
select a.*,
b.Par1To7days,
c.Par8To30days,
d.Par31To60days,
e.Par61To90days,
f.Par91To120days,
g.Par121To180days --,
--h.Par181AndAbovedays
from

filterNegativeArrears a
left join computePar1To7days b
on a.loanid=b.loanid
left join computePar8To30days c
on a.loanid=c.loanid
left join computePar31To60days d
on a.loanid=d.loanid
left join computePar61To90days e
on a.loanid=e.loanid
left join computePar91To120days f
on a.loanid=f.loanid
left join computePar121To180days g
on a.loanid=g.loanid
--left join computePar181AndAbovedays h
--  on a.loanid=h.loanid
```

the code above joins the computed age

The code is working fine and calculating fine

[image]

but when I add more join in the selection I get an error

```
left join computePar181AndAbovedays h
on a.loanid=h.loanid
```

The problem is I started encountering the error:

[image]

> An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for
>   potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify
>   them.

I still need more table to join with my query.

Can you suggest ways to simplify this query is highly appreciated

Comment: Side note: You should absolutely avoid having locale-specific date formats in any query. Eg `DATEADD(day,-7,'12/19/2016')` in your query. Always use the ISO format as illustrated in [DATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx). Formats: `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYYMMDD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obviously running into a limit there and budging that limit will not be possible with the query you have. Follow the advice given in the error message: simplify.

How? Well you have a multitude of CTE's defined. Another way of writing your query is by materializing the CTE's in temporary tables before the actual query and then using the temporary tables instead.

---

For example, this CTE:

```
membersWithLoans as -- gets members with loan
(
select a.memberid, a.loanid,a.loanamt,a.intamt
from loanmst a
where loandt<='12/19/2016'
and status = 'O'
)
```

Can be be materialized to a temporary table:

```
select a.memberid, a.loanid,a.loanamt,a.intamt
into #membersWithLoans
from loanmst a
where loandt<='12/19/2016'
and status = 'O'
```

This will create a temporary table `#membersWithLoans` that can be used in further temporary table creations or in your final query.

To illustrate further, suppose you have materialized all your CTE's to temporary tables, you would have no more `WITH` clause. You would then finally use the temporary tables in your final `SELECT` query:

```
-- create all temporary tables (one of them being #filterNegativeArrears)

select 
    a.*,
    -- the rest of your selections
from
    #filterNegativeArrears a
    -- the rest of the joined temporary tables
-- the rest of your query (WHERE, ORDER BY etc)
```

Comment: @Mandz Hi Mandz. No, what you define in a `WITH` clause are CTE's aka **C**ommon **T**able **E**xpressions. Compare them to views you define temporarily to be used in one query. The CTE's are not materialized; when your query is run the CTE's are expanded in your query similar to how you would write your query with derived tables.

Comment: That's a new code for me. I'll try to read on temporary tables. I thought sql "with clause" are temporary tables. I quick question though can I join my current sub queries with the new temporary table? Sample I'll put my output to a temp1 then I'll join the temp1 to the sub query previously?

Comment: @Mandz Yes, you can. I'll quickly update my answer to illustrate.

Comment: This querry is being feed from my program to the database. My question is after I get my final result from the joined tables do I need some code to dispose the temporary tables? sample I called my code dbsqlConnect.Close();. Will the temporary table stay or will it be erased? Frankly I am using this query to generate computed reports. So that i would know how to adopt with my program. Thx for the time

Comment: @Mandz If you have connection pooling eg from a JBoss application server, you will certainly have to drop the temporary tables right after the `SELECT` statement. So your query would be as whole: **(1)** create the temporary tables, **(2)** the select statement referencing the temporary tables and finally **(3)** drop all the temporary tables created in step 1 (eg `DROP TABLE #filterNegativeArrears; DROP TABLE ...`). This all in one SQL script.

Comment: thx for the suggestion although I'm still working on the code. I'll choose this an answer after I could fully implement this and fully test.

Comment: Thx and Yes it is working. I'm still on the process on implementing all logic hopefully.The code posted above is only half of the overall report ^_^. I'll choose this answer after I Implement on my program so that I can still follow up if there are still error. One question though is "How many temp table can I create or what is the limit of temp tables?"

Comment: @Mandz There is no hard-coded limit to the amount of temporary tables. Keep in mind though that temporary tables are created in a separate database called `tempdb`. It is a good idea to have this `tempdb` located on a disk that has enough capacity. By default (on installation of SQL Server) it is placed in the installation folder. If that is a drive where your Windows is also installed and there is little space to grow, in some circumstances you might run out of disk space. It is a good idea to put it on a disk with enough space to grow (like regular databases).

Comment: This codes works wonders. It is working on my reports and on my programming language.I successfully implemented it. One last question what is the cons of this code? thank you very much

Comment: @Mandz I'm very happy to hear that =). I've listed several possible cons already. One is with connection pooling eg in JBoss or any other connection pooling mechanism. The sessions in that case are pooled and not closed. If you would forget to explicitely drop a temporary table and another user would reuse the session and executes the same code would get a `table #... already exists`. Normally temporary tables are automatically dropped when a session is closed, but they are not closed in a connection pooled environment.

Comment: @Mandz Another is if you keep the `tempdb` on a disk with insufficient space, as I've once experienced at a client. The tempdb was located on the C drive along with the OS installation and all software. There was little space left and there was a routine that had huge amounts of intermediary results stored in temporary tables. When the drive was full, we were getting application errors due to insufficient disk space. This is easily solved by adding another partition for the tempdb, or easier is to place tempdb on a drive with sufficient space to grow (like you would do with regular databases).

Comment: @Mandz Other than that I can't really think of real downsides. I use temporary tables a lot for my work because in certain calculations there are huge amounts of intermediate data. It's real inefficient to calculate them all in one query in derived tables or CTE's. Some queries *demand* intermediate results to be populated in temporary tables. Added bonus is that you can create primary keys and indexes on them, which can be an additional speed-up and the primary keys can be an extra safe-guard against mistakes in writing the query (require unique data).

Comment: @Mandz Side note: note that even if you're not using temporary tables explcitely that some queries will spill over data to `tempdb`. That happens when your server runs out of memory or certain constructs require the spill over to happen to tempdb. So it's always have the tempdb located on a disk with sufficient space to grow, ideally *not* on the drive where you have the OS and all programs installed.

Comment: Super thanks for the tip. I'll consider those on my future projects